# Spark Scala: How to transform a column in a DF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe in Spark with many columns and a udf that I defined. I want the same dataframe back, except with one column transformed. Furthermore, my udf takes in a string and returns a timestamp. Is there an easy way to do this? I tried

```
val test = myDF.select("my_column").rdd.map(r => getTimestamp(r))
```

but this returns an RDD and just with the transformed column.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you really need to use your function, I can suggest two options:

1. Using map / toDF:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
   import sqlContext.implicits._

   def getTimestamp: (String => java.sql.Timestamp) = // your function here

   val test = myDF.select("my_column").rdd.map {
     case Row(string_val: String) => (string_val, getTimestamp(string_val))
   }.toDF("my_column", "new_column")
   ```
2. Using UDFs (`UserDefinedFunction`):

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

   def getTimestamp: (String => java.sql.Timestamp) = // your function here

   val newCol = udf(getTimestamp).apply(col("my_column")) // creates the new column
   val test = myDF.withColumn("new_column", newCol) // adds the new column to original DF
   ```

---

**Alternatively**,

If you just want to transform a `StringType` column into a `TimestampType` column you can use the `unix_timestamp` [column function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) available since Spark SQL 1.5:

```
val test = myDF
  .withColumn("new_column", unix_timestamp(col("my_column"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
  .cast("timestamp"))
```

Note: For spark 1.5.x, it is necessary to multiply the result of `unix_timestamp` by `1000` before casting to timestamp (issue [SPARK-11724](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11724)). The resulting code would be:

```
val test = myDF
  .withColumn("new_column", (unix_timestamp(col("my_column"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") *1000L)
  .cast("timestamp"))
```

*Edit: Added udf option*

Comment: Thanks for the help. The only issue i'm having is that when I do df.withColumn("start_date", unix_timestamp(df1("start_date"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp")), my dates are getting converted wrong. For example: 2013-08-12 06:40:54 gets converted to 1970-01-16 22:18:09.654. Do you happen to know what might be going on?

Comment: For spark 1.5 you must multiply by 1000 before the cast